# Go back to command line in bash

Tags: bash, function, built-in, reserved-words

I am using this code to exit my program:

```
exit(){
        clear
        exit 0
}
```

This clears the screen, but does not exit the script and just leaves a blinking caret in the terminal. Is it possible that this does not work within a function?

I tried this method to exit:

```
trap "exit 1" TERM
export TOP_PID=$$

exit()
{
   clear
   kill -s TERM $TOP_PID
}
```

But this produces a similar result as the first idea.

Comment: The `exit` function uses `exit`, which just runs the function again... and again and again and again forever. Don't use the names of standard commands for your functions; pick a different name.

Answer (score 2):

Avoid using names of built-in commands as function names. You can get a list of the built-in commands using `help`.

To answer your question:

Replace `exit 0` with `command exit 0` to force usage of built-in command.